# Image of diverging lens

Tags: optics, conventions, lenses

In my book it is written as for all position of real object in case of diverging lens , image will be virtual and dimished on the same side of lens.

Here what they mean by ' same side of lens '

And according to me it should be real image as

We know 1/f = (1/v)-(1/u)

Subtituting the  values of u and f with signs we get ,

(-1/f) = (1/v) -(-1/u)

From this we know v is also negative so it should be virtual .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here what they mean by ' same side of lens '

The virtual image is on the same side of the lens as the real object.

[image]

You have stated that 1/f = (1/v)-(1/u) and your link in the comments means that you are probably trying to use the [Cartesian sign convention](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/geoopt/lenseq.html#c2) with the following diagram showing the important points with distances measured from the pole of the lens $O$ with right as positive.

[image]

Since it is a diverging lens the focal length $f$ is negative and with the object placed between $F_1$ and $O$ the object distance $u$ is also negative.

As $ \frac 1 v = \frac 1 u + \frac 1 f$ and with $u$ and $f$ both negative, the image distance $v$ must also be negative.

So the image is on the same side of the lens as the object and virtual.